# How to sort a list of objects based on their properties?

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of objects based on their Ids.

When I create a function that compares the Id of to objects in a list, It gets the error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3867   'BobControl::compareId': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member list.sort   c:\users\wil\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\list.sort\list.sort\source.cpp   32
```

This code was used to test the issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Bob {
public:
    Bob::Bob(int id) {
        _id = id;
    }
    int getId() const { return _id; }


private:
    int _id = 0;

};     

//testing lists
class BobControl {
public:

    bool compareId(const Bob& first, const Bob& second)
    {
        return (first.getId()  < second.getId());
    }
    void testCompar() {
        bobs.sort(compareId);
    }

    void controlBobs() {
        list<Bob>::iterator lit;
        bobs.push_back(Bob(0));
        bobs.push_back(Bob(1));
        bobs.push_back(Bob(5));
        bobs.push_back(Bob(3));

        testCompar();


        for (lit = bobs.begin(); lit != bobs.end(); lit++) {
            cout << (*lit).getId() << endl;
        }
    }
private:
    list<Bob> bobs;      
};

int main() {

    BobControl bobc;

    bobc.controlBobs();

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to sort object, try using algorithm sort. That way it's become simpler

Comment: @AchmadJP: `std::list` has its own [`sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) method. `std::sort()` is not any easiest to use than `std::list<T>::sort()`.  And they both have the same restriction mentioned in MichaelAlbers' answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `compareId()` needs to be a static function or a standalone function. The list's `sort()` method does not accept an object on which it can call a non-static object method.